# Is it possible to view the highest rep users by tag?

Tags: support

[This question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11688/108003) made me curious about something. It pointed out that [the only gold tag badges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) that have been awarded were for Minecraft.

Given how big of a deal Fallout 4 was/is, and how much the site was devoted to it at the time it was released, it seems like maybe someone should have received a gold badge. I'm curious how close we came as a community.

I suspected that I had nearly the most, if not the most, rep in the Fallout 4 tag. I checked, and only [Kalina and I have silver badges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/308/fallout-4).

Is there any way to actually see the rep totals in that tag for users across the site, similar to the [rep leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/7/year/gaming/2016-01-01/108003#108003) but restricted by tag? Is this one of the things you get as part of the [moderator tools](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)?

Comment: As a followup: [kalina has met the rep barrier](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/fallout-4/topusers), but it's not across enough posts, so we were pretty close to a gold there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can click on the tag, then click on top users to view who has the highest score for each badge. 
[image]
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/overwatch/topusers

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks.

Comment: yep. Happy to help. @DCShannon